# How to get the command name when a command not found error occurs discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have made an event called on_command_error which intercepts the orginal command error. In that event it sends to the channel the command was executed in.
"The command you have executed is not found".
I want it to be able to say.
"The command {commandname} has not been found".
I don't know how to get the command name.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("The command you have executed is not found.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may not be the best way of doing this, but a solution I discovered is:

```
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send(f"The command {error} you have executed is not found. use the command !help for a list of available commands")
```